# How do you give a variable a value as the result of an if statement?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, set

I'm trying to get "p" to flip/flop 0 and 1, when gpio.input(i) = true

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code - it doesn't work!

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time as time

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)

i = 15
o = 11
t = 0.3
p = 0

gpio.setup(i, gpio.IN)
gpio.setup(o, gpio.OUT)

gpio.output(o, True)

while True:
    if gpio.input(i) and p == 0:
        print("P = 1")
        p = 1
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        if (gpio.input(i)) and p == 1:
            p = 0       

while True:
    if p == 1:
        gpio.output(o, False)
        time.sleep(t)
        gpio.output(o, True)
        time.sleep(t)
```

Comment: What output *do* you see?

Comment: Note that the second loop will *never* be executed as your first loop never ends.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Which could point to the flipping not being the real problem.

Comment: Also, because you have a second call to gpio.input() in the else clause, it's being called either once or twice per loop, depending on the value of p. I doubt that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cracked it!! - the key was to have the code wait for the gpio input, then set p to 1, and then run the output while loop until gpio input goes from zero (not pressed), to 1 again (ie: pressing the button)

(THANKS FOR PEOPLE'S INPUT) :0) xx

> > See code:<<

import RPi.GPIO as gpio

import time as time

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)

gpio.cleanup()

i = 15

o = 11

t = 0.3

p = 0

gpio.setup(i, gpio.IN)

gpio.setup(o, gpio.OUT)

gpio.output(o, True)

while True:

```
if gpio.input(i):

    if gpio.input(i) and p == 0:

        p = 1

        time.sleep(0.5)

        while not(gpio.input(i)) and p == 1:

            gpio.output(o, False)

            time.sleep(t)

            gpio.output(o, True)

            time.sleep(t) 

        else:

            while gpio.input(i):

                p = 0

                time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is this: gpio.input(i) reads the input and then the input is gone, so in the else-part it evaluates to false.

Try this:

```
if gpio.input(i):
  if p == 0:
     p = 1
   else:
     p = 0
```

Comment: Interestingly, the line: 'print("P = 1")' works. P = 1 is displayed on the screen. I'll give this a go to - thx!

Comment: Yes, that's logical, because the problem lies in the else-part only.

Another option for the code is this:
    if gpio.input(i):
        p = 1 - p
Or, of course, the XOR operator mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

The XOR operator, `^` can be used to flip-flop the value:

```
val = gpio.input(i)
p = val ^ p
```

Notice how `^` behaves:

```
In [3]: 1 ^ 0
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: 1 ^ 1
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: 0 ^ 1
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: 0 ^ 0
Out[6]: 0
```

So when `val == 1`, `val ^ p` flip-flops `p`.
When `val == 0`, `p` is left unchanged.

Note that the above assumes `gpio.input` returns either 0 or 1. If it can return other values, then `val ^ p` might also evaluate to some value other than 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on XOR - will come in useful - my issue seems to be tho, that once the logic is satisfied, the resulting action of setting 'p' to 1 or 0, isn't happening, but the method 'print' is being invoked??

Comment: How are you determining that `p` is not being set? Perhaps try `print(p)` to see what the value of `p` is in the `while-loop`.